# PHP exec() function command finished but last function not execute

Tags: php, linux, database, ffmpeg

The PHP file should execute FFmpeg command after this command finished it should take data into the database. However, I found that the `exec($command--FFmpeg)` has been completed and it run pretty well but the data is not in the database.

I have set `php.ini ignore_user_abort = On`

It could run the PHP process in the background

my could is as follows

```
set_time_limit(0);
$tumbfileName = time();
$filepath = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/files/video/";
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i ' . dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).$content . ' -c:v libx264 -strict -2 ' . $filepath . "post_" . $tumbfileName . '.mp4';
exec($cmd, $output, $error);

$cmdImg="ffmpeg -y -ss 2 -i ".dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).$content." -vframes 1 -f image2 -s 400*300 ".$filepath . "notice_thumb_" . $tumbfileName . '.jpg';
//$cmdImg = "ffmpeg -i " . dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).$content . " -f image2 -ss 10 -s 400*300 -vframes 10 " . $filepath . "notice_thumb_" . $tumbfileName . '.jpg';
exec($cmdImg, $outputImg, $errorImg);
$data = array(
        'content' => "/files/video/"."post_" . $tumbfileName . '.mp4',
        'author' => 'management',
        'deadline' => $deadline,
        'type' => $type,
        'datetime' => time(),
        'thumb' => "/files/video/"."notice_thumb_" . $tumbfileName . '.jpg'
);                                                          
$flag = $this->db->insert('notice_info', $data);
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Perhaps there's an issue with your db connection.

Comment: The database function is no problem. I have try to just insert data into database without ffmpeg

Comment: well I see you're using `'type' => $type` and there's no $type variable

Comment: That's no matter. it's just a part of code. I haven't paste all code on that:)